# What does the "text" nodes represent in this html form?

Tags: javascript, dom

There's a form in my html page, I'm trying to access this element to see the child nodes it has.

When printing out the  variable "form" which represents the form in the page I get the following result:

```
<form id="frm1" action="" mehtod="">
    <input type="text" name="input1_frm1">
    <input type="password" name="input2_frm1">
    <input type="submit" value="Send form 1">
</form>
```

As its name sugguests, `form.childNodes` returns an array containing the node elements in the form. So I get this output

```
[text, input, text, input, text, input, text]
```

However I can't recognize what the "text" nodes represent.

Comment: My best guess would have to be whitespace between the actual HTML tags. You can check this easily by just removing all the whitespace and see if the nodes appear there as well.

Comment: You guess right, it's actually the spaces caused by tabulation before the `<input>` tags

Comment: Yeah that's it.
Problem solved.